# React Parent Component Not Rendering Child Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Basic question, but we all start somewhere.

**I have a parent Nav.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import navLink from './navLink'

class Nav extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="bb bt b--black-20 tc center bg-white">
          <navLink />
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Nav.displayName = 'Nav'

export default Nav
```

Here's the file that won't get displayed:

**navLink.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

const navigationLinks = [
  { name: '1', link: '/', router: true },
  { name: '2', link: '#' }
]

const renderLink = (link, i) => {
  if (link.router === true) {
    return (
      <Link href={link.link}>
        <a className="yellow" key={i}>{link.name}</a>
      </Link>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <a className="red" key={i} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={link.link}>{link.name}</a>
    )
  }
}

const navLink = () => (
  <nav className="container">
    {navigationLinks.map(link => renderLink(link))}
  </nav>
)

navLink.displayName = 'navLink'

export default navLink
```

I'm my problem is super basic, but I have no idea how to resolve this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are importing from 'navLink' but the file it is in is 'navBar'?

Comment: @ChrisCousins great catch. That was an error in the SO post but the real file is navLink.js

I updated the SO post to reflect that.

Comment: np - can you please put what *does* get rendered? is there any output at all?

Comment: Nothing gets generated. I do see in react developer tools: <navLink /> == r so its there. It's something in my navLink.js:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is `navLink` with a small letter, it should be `NavLink` as `RenderLink` if you want to use it.

In JSX lower case are considered to be a `HTML` tags, `HTML`  is not have no a `navLink` tag  so it's just didn't displayed.

Comment: Your commit was the issue for me. lowercase. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized

> The first part of a JSX tag determines the type of the React element.
>   Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component. These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the named variable, so if you use the JSX  expression, Foo must be in scope.

see: [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

### Render links

```
const SimpleLink = ({link}) => (
      <Link href={link.link}>
        <a className="yellow">{link.name}</a>
      </Link>
);

const RenderRouter = ({link}) => (
    <a className="red" target="_blank" href={link.link}>{link.name}</a>
);

const renderLink = link => link.router ? 
    ( <SimpleLink key={i} link={link}/> ) :
    ( <RenderRouter key={i} link={link}/> );

...

const NavLink = () => (
  <div className="container">
    { navigationLinks.map((link, i) => renderLink(link, i))}
  </div>
);

...
export default NavLink
```

### Import

```
import NavLink from './navLink.js'
```

### Nav Component

```
class Nav extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <nav className="bb bt b--black-20 tc center bg-white">
          <NavLink />
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

See: [working example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KqBPwtyEq-72XRbiOZn)

### Fix proptypes

> react-router may provide propType definitions for it already, but whether they do or not, you'd still need to explicitly connect them.

```
Rend.propTypes = {
  link: React.PropTypes.shape({
      link: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }),
};
```

See: [eslint-plugin-react/issues/1109](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1109#issuecomment-286052521)

Comment: I didn't test it, I would make a `webpackbin`